# Generic invariant sort

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a set of objects.  I want to sort them in such a way that a future sort of a (possibly different) set of objects is guaranteed to be consistent with my current sort.  In other languages, I would do this by using the address.  But in C#, the address is considered unsafe.  I'd rather avoid that.  So how can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: It's unclear how the address is an advantage here.  If they are different objects they would have a different address.  Why does address help?

Comment: Can  you please explain what "consistent with current sort" means in your case? My understanding is there is no "less" comparison between objects - as result you can't just sort them; but somehow there is 
"consistent" relationship between 2 unrelated sets of objects... On one hand it feels like you should be able to implement merge sort trivially because every 2 sets of items have some defined relationship, but I'm at loss what the relationship is...

Comment: If I have objects A and B, then on occasions when both are in the list, A always gets sorted before B, or A always gets sorted after B.  I don't care which, just so the result is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have no identifying information in your object that you could sort on. Give each object an artificial such property.

```
class MyClass { public Guid SortKey = Guid.NewGuid(); }
```

And sort on that key. If you can't extend the objects to be sorted, keep the sort key externally stored:

```
Dictionary<object, Guid> sortKeyByObject;
```

Instead of Guids, you can also use an incrementing integer counter. Be sure to use it in a thread-safe way and be aware of wrapping issues (so use a `long`).

Do not use `object.GetHashCode` as it is not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 0):

Sort using `Object.GetHashCode()`.

`GetHasCode()` will (unless you've overridden it yourself, badly) return a consistent value within the same execution, which I assume is what you want because you mentioned memory addressed...

Comment: Not _guaranteed_ to be unique for non-identical objects.

Comment: If two objects happen to get the same hash code they end up next to each other in unspecified order.

Comment: True, then there isn't exactly a lot to play with; the only other alternative is `ToString()`.
If ordering _really_ matters, then you wouldn't use a generic interface, you'd use a specific one: `IComparable<T>`